# How do you identify which IDs have an increasing value over time in another column in a Python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a data frame with 3 columns:

```
| id | value |    date   |
+====+=======+===========+
|  1 |   50  |  1-Feb-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |  100  |  5-Feb-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |  200  |  6-Jun-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |  500  |  1-Dec-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  2 |   10  |  6-Jul-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  3 |  500  |  1-Mar-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  3 |  200  |  5-Apr-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  3 |  100  | 30-Jun-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  3 |   10  | 25-Dec-19 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

ID column contains the ID of a particular person.
Value column contains the value of their transaction.
Date column contains the date of their transaction.

Is there a way in Python to identify ID 1 as the ID with the increasing value of transactions over time?

I'm looking for some way I can extract ID 1 as my desired ID with increasing value of transactions, filter out ID 2 because it doesn't have enough transactions to analyze a trend and also filter out ID 3 as it's trend of transactions is declining over time.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: If you want a [tag:python] solution, why are you tagging the [tag:r] programming language? (If you are amenable to either language, then you should probably be explicit about that, otherwise you'll get more comments like mine :-)

Comment: Hi, removed the sql and r tags. Im open to those options but prefer python so i'll leave the python tag only as suggested. Regarding the first comment, how should data be posted? I dont have any actual data, I'm exploring a concept only so just showed what the data would look like in such a problem. Should I post the data as a table that is copy-able instead of a sample image?

Comment: I don't know off-hand the python equivalent of R's `dput(...)`, which dumps a structure that is unambiguous and perfectly rehydratable (in a sense). Perhaps build it programmatically? `d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}` and `df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)` is a way to give potential answerers clear data to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform(lambda x : \
                      np.where(x.diff()>0,'incresase',
                      np.where(x.diff()<0,'decrease','--')))

df = df.groupby('id').new.agg(['last'])
df
```

Output:

```
      last
id  
1   increase
2   --
3   decrease
```

Only increasing ID:

```
increasingList = df[(df['last']=='increase')].index.values
print(increasingList)
```

Result:

```
[1]
```

**Assuming this won't happen**

```
1  50
1  100
1  50
```

***If so, then:***

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform(lambda x : \
                      np.where(x.diff()>0,'increase',
                      np.where(x.diff()<0,'decrease','--')))
df
```

Output:

```
    value   new
id      
1   50  --
1   100 increase
1   200 increase
2   10  --
3   500 --
3   300 decrease
3   100 decrease
```

Concat strings:

```
df = df.groupby(['id'])['new'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
df
```

Intermediate Result:

```
    id  new
0   1   --,increase,increase
1   2   --
2   3   --,decrease,decrease
```

Check if decrease exist in a row / only "--" exists. Drop them

```
df = df.drop(df[df['new'].str.contains("dec")].index.values)
df = df.drop(df[(df['new']=='--')].index.values)
df
```

Result:

```
    id  new
0   1   --,increase,increase
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps group by the id, and check that the sorted values are the same whether sorted by values or by date:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').apply( lambda x:
...    (
...        x.sort_values('value', ignore_index=True)['value'] == x.sort_values('date', ignore_index=True)['value']
...    ).all()
... )
id
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

**EDIT:**

To make `id=2` not True, we can do this instead:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').apply( lambda x:
...    (
...        (x.sort_values('value', ignore_index=True)['value'] == x.sort_values('date', ignore_index=True)['value'])
...        & (len(x) > 1)
...    ).all()
... )
id
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: 2 should not be true

Comment: @AtanuCSE Updated